# Which permissions do I need to call requestPermission() - Android

Tags: android, permissions, android-8.0-oreo

I'm setting up some permissions in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES"/>
```

I request the permission on runtime for all of those permissions.
But somehow the permission `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` does not need to call `requestPermission()`. If I try to call it anyway, the popup never appears.

Is there a list of permissions i need to call at runtime?
My current android version is 8.0.0.

Thanks

Comment: *Which permissions do I need to call requestPermission()*  The one which in documentation has protection level dangerous ... asking for list of something is off-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on type of permission you are requesting for. There are two kind of permissions in Android: **Normal and Dangerous Permissions**

If there are dangerous, you must request for it at runtime for API level 23 and above.

For more info you should read following documentation: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous